# Data is not correct in output when change to 2021 in pandas dataframe using python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The below python function was used to get report for previous,present and Feature year.
It Was running correctly for year 2019,2020 and 2021.

but when i tried to pull report for year 2020,2021 and 2022, output file is throwing error.
i have doubt whether the issue with function or data.....

May someone please suggest do i need to change something in the function code.

Code.

```
def get_date(s_year, s_month):
    '''Function to get date from year and month
       Arg: 
         (s_year, s_month as <string, int>)
       Returns: 
         date as datetime.date'''
    dt = pd.to_datetime(int(s_year)*10000+int(s_month)*100+1, format = "%Y%m%d")
    return dt.date()

def get_last_day(idt):
    '''Function to get the last date of a month
       Arg: 
          idt as date
       Returns:
          last date as datetime.date
       '''
    dt = pd.to_datetime(idt) + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
    return dt.date()
```

This function i was using as below.

```
df_periods['EssBy'] = [get_last_day(get_date(x, y)) for x, y in df_periods.Year_Period.str.split('-').tolist()]
df_periods.iloc[:, 1:4] = df_periods.iloc[:, 1:4].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce') # convert to datetime
df_periods.iloc[:, 1:4] = df_periods.iloc[:, 1:4].apply(lambda x: x.dt.date) # convert to datetime.date

# Get the start date as the minimum of Year_Period
start_date = pd.to_datetime(df_periods.Start.min()).date()

years = [start_date.year, start_date.year+1, start_date.year+2, start_date.year+3] #isin requires array
```

Please help.

Comment: What is error here? I guess problem is in data.

Comment: lets see that error message!

Comment: I cannot see it, it seems you forget paste text of error to question.

Comment: I have to say that is a very weird way of creating a date (the integer calculations in your get_date function). Why not simply do `"%04d%02d01" % (int(s_year), int(s_month))` instead?